PrimeVue Forms API: TypeScript Error When Accessing $form Field States
I'm using the PrimeVue Forms API with TypeScript, but I encounter TypeScript errors when trying to access form field states via the $form object. This occurs even when following the documentation examples.
Here’s the error I’m seeing:
Property 'username' does not exist on type '{ register: (field: string, options: any) => any; reset: () => void; valid: boolean; states: Record<string, FormFieldState>; }'

Code:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Form } from '@primevue/forms'
import Button from 'primevue/button'
</script>

<template>
  <Form v-slot="$form" class="flex flex-col gap-4 w-full sm:w-56">
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-1">
      <InputText name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" fluid />
      <Message v-if="$form.username?.invalid" severity="error" size="small" variant="simple">
        {{ $form.username.error?.message }}
      </Message>
    </div>
    <Button type="submit" severity="secondary" label="Submit" />
  </Form>
</template>

Question:
Is this issue a bug in PrimeVue's Forms API, or am I missing some configuration/setup to get this working with TypeScript? Are there any better workarounds or fixes available?

Types in templates themselves have flaky support because it's semi-official and relied on previously third-party tool (vue-tsc). Regarding this case it looks like it has been just fixed https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/commit/464366068227cf807417257366b939739e3dc617#diff-d1154cb259c1370227f4fe264dc56efb15b70651352d69aa11ee005dce3cfb6cR237, it's not released yet. The types suggest you could use $form.states.username... in the current version instead
